# Set-up scspell like behavior for the flyspell

Tags: flyspell

I was trying to enable [scspell](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scspell3k) like behavior for Flyspell but still can't succeed.

Shortly - Flyspell parses "DemoWord" like "DemoWord" and scspell splits is into two words demo and word.

I was trying to change [flyspell-get-word](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/emacs/blob/master/lisp/textmodes/flyspell.el#L1300) function; particularly - to change the regular expression but, perhaps, there is a more natural way?